# emergency lighting conversion

Tags: led, power, batteries

I have a pocket flashlight (27 Leds) that runs on 3 aaa batts. I would like to use this item to replace my bulbs in my "emergency lighting. The bulbs exhaust the battery too quickly (90 minutes). The master lead acid cell(standby) is 6volt at 4.5 amps.

WHAT do I need to convert to these units? It would be two flashlight heads for each "emergency lite".

This is the lighting for exit doors and hallway lighting during "power" outages.

Comment: You can get LED based "non-maintained" emergency lights (e.g. [1](http://www.tradehardware.net/shop/led-non-maintained-emergency-light-bulkhead/), [2](http://www.fruugo.us/lyon-lighting-non-maintained-3-hour-compact-led-twin-spot/p-1690831)). Otherwise if replacing fluorescent bulbs you'd need to replace the control circuitry - or at least the part that provides the start-up voltage etc for the fluorescent tube.

Comment: Bear in mind, depending on where you are, changes to emergency lighting may void compliance to fire safety laws for your area.

Answer (score 1):

Since White LEDs typically run at 3.2V, one could use two low Vce(sat) NPN's from Diodes Inc. and make a CC sink using Ie=20 to 30mA x27 @.65V using Re=0.65 Ohm or whatever matches 1A sink and Rb= 33xRe to give the best results with above assumptions. Power rating of Re must be rated >=1W.

CC design is common knowledge and repeated on this site.

For those new to CC sink solutions.   for review, the base resistor can be used to enable or pulled up to Vin biases the collector to saturate must have IB=10% of IC but for 'diode inc" HYPERBARRIER PN diodes parts 2 or 3%  Ib is minimum but more will reduce  Vce(sat) better than any other Silicon parts.

Treat this design as a 2 pin design on Vcc side is a current source, or on ground side as a current sink. Either way works.  Any parts work with > 2V drop @1A, Diodes Inc parts can achieve down to 1V drop at low battery.

A more efficient design might use LIPO 4V cells with a fixed resistor  rather than 6V Lead acid. to drive 3.2V LEDs.

[image]

Comment: So why specifically use BJTs from Diodes Inc?

Comment: If there was a Golf Major championship for lowest scores in Vce(sat) and ESR for Bipolar devices. They will win.  THey use a MOS process instead of a Bipolar procersslike Schottky diodes to make PN junctions with better scores for low dropout switches and current sinks. The result is lower variation in LED current with a fixed resistor and variable battery voltage. 27x 5mm LEDs @20mA in parallel have an ESR of 15/27 ~500mOhm .   CC sinks traditionally have a darlington type dropout (Vce+Vbe) so lower saturation voltages for both reduces these variations . Their design is patented also.

Comment: @Larry Can you provide a part number for one of these devices please?

Comment: @Larry My "shill alarm" just went off, pretty loudly. Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

You can buy LED-replacements for most types of bulb these days with no adaption / alteration required.

Failing that, going for one that's close to the right spec and requires no external support circuitry will be by far the easiest answer - short of just buying a new LED light unit complete.

As with all these things, it depends how you value your time and how interested you are in the problem itself Vs just having it working.

Comment: "You can buy LED-replacements for most types of bulb". Also for 6V bulbs?

Comment: Yes. 1st step would be to identify the bulb in the backup luminaire - I have 5ft maintained fluorescent tubes with 4.5v cells in them, so battery voltage is a poor indicator of what the bulb might be.